# Adding a font to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, font

I got a shapefile in which a column in the attribute table has a specific font (they send me this font file). How can I add this font to ArcGIS to display this column correctly?

Comment: if it is true type (.ttf) it can be added to the systems fonts.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to install this font on your system (on recent window version right click on the font file then choose install)(after installing it, it will be available for all application but you may need to restart ArcMap to be able to use it).

When the font is available on your system you need to set your table display option to use this font by clicking on the "Table Options" icon on the Table window toolbar then click Appearance you will get a window where you could set the new font for your table (this will affect all field but only for that specific table) ([ESRI help about that](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/setting-general-table-display-options.htm)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works

Comment: For permanent use change it at, Customise -> Acrmap Options -> tables